# Angular (1.5.0) ng-router not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, oclazyload, angularjs-1.5

I'm using **angular,angular-animate,angular-route** v.1.5.0 , **ui-grid** v. 3.0.7
**ocLazyLoad** v. 1.0.9.

I get this error :

```
TypeError: a is not a function
at d (angular-animate.js:2141)
at angular-animate.js:2131
at h (angular-animate.js:3174)
at Array.d.push.fn (angular-animate.js:3020)
at c (angular-animate.js:423)
at b (angular-animate.js:393)
at angular-animate.js:3042
at m.$digest (angular.js:16714)
at angular.js:16859
at e (angular.js:5804)
```

And each page is loaded under the other

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wn4p.png)

Any suggestion? Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
TypeError: $$animateJs is not a function
at prepareAnimation (angular-animate.js:2141)
at initDriverFn (angular-animate.js:2131)
at invokeFirstDriver (angular-animate.js:3174)
at Array.triggerAnimationStart (angular-animate.js:3020)
at nextTick (angular-animate.js:423)
at scheduler (angular-animate.js:393)
at angular-animate.js:3042
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16714)
at angular.js:16859
at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5804)
```

Comment: please share your code and use the unminified version of angular and angular-animate, errors will be way more explicit.

Comment: @tanou  what version ?

Comment: Hi francx, welcome to StackOverflow! It would be helpful if you provide your code sample here so we can help diagnose your problem.

Comment: use unminified version of javascript.. to get exact place where error is happening..

Comment: when you download angular, you can include either angular.min.js or angular.js. The '.min' significate that this is a minified version, so the code is "compressed" and obliterate. So function and variables are renamed. That's why the stacktrace says 'a' instead of the real function name. So instead of including 'angular.min.js' in your scripts import, include 'angular.js'. Same for angular-animate.

Comment: @tanou I imported "angular.js etc..", but I get the same error

Comment: you've imported angular.js and angular-animate.js ? and the stacktrace is the same ? There should be named function instead of 'a', 'd', 'h' ..etc

Comment: No i was wrong! Sorry , I've updated the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem , just include **ui-grid.js** in your body **( NOT WITH OCLAZYLOAD)**.